# Can't call web-api with angularjs 2

Tags: api, angular

I'm trying to call a (working) web api using angularjs2. But it says 'Collection not found'. It seems straightforward but still doesn't work. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question doesn't contain a lot of information. Please check the help menu how to ask good questions. Please add more information (code) about what you tried, where you failed, what error messages you got, ...

Comment: Please come up with code. show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you is the InMemoryDataService? If so, try commenting it out.

I had a similar issue calling my WebAPI. In the end I had to comment out the InMemoryDataService - as soon as I did this then the error went away and I was able to hit my WebAPI: 
[AngularJS 2 : Getting data from json file not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432108/angularjs-2-getting-data-from-json-file-not-working)