# Angular2 POST Observable Request returns a not readable JSON Object

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing, single-page-application

I'am using an Angular2 POST Request with Observable to a Node API.
I keep getting a strange JSON Object back as Response.

Response from Node API App - via Chrome Console:

```
{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false,"source":
{"_isScalar":false,"source":{"_isScalar":false},"operator":
{"delay":500,"scheduler":{"actions":[],"active":false}}},"operator":
{}},"operator":{"caught":"[Circular]"}}
```

Angular2 Code:

```
login2(): Observable<any> {

    this.url = 'http://localhost:3080/user/login';

    this.obj.email =  'jhon.doe@foo.de';
    this.obj.password = 'pass';

    let formObj = this.form.getRawValue();
    let serializedForm = JSON.stringify(formObj);

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 

    var obsRequest = this.http.post(this.url, this.obj, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch( (error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') );


    console.log(JSON.stringify(obsRequest, this.avoidCircular(obsRequest)));

    return obsRequest;
}
```

P.S. `avoidCircular` is an extra workaround for the javaScript built-in `JSON.stringify`, cause when I don't use it get the following error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

avoidCircual Code:

```
avoidCircular(objCens) {
    var i = 0;
    return function(k, v) {
        if(i !== 0 && typeof(objCens) === 'object' && typeof(v) == 'object' && objCens == v) 
        return '[Circular]'; 
        if(i >= 29) 
        return '[Unknown]';
        ++i; 
        return v;  
    }
}
```

The API call is working fine via Postman!

Any idea how to fix this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obsRequest` is not the response from your request, it is the request observable. In order to receive the response you need to `subscribe` to it.

```
var obsRequest = this.http.post(this.url, this.obj, options)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch( (error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') );

obsRequest.subscribe((response)=> console.log(response));
```

I suggest you to read the http module of the official documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: Thanks! you saved my day. 
But I also would like to mention that I did face another issue which I was able to fix. It has to do with the Angular InMemoryBackendService built-in service. I was using it in the same app - Just testing - for other component.
It seems like it's doing a kind of 'redirect' from http.get method... after commenting it out in app.component, it did work.
See: [Error: Collection not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38432108/angularjs-2-getting-data-from-json-file-not-working)

Comment: @k.vincent well I'm not really familiar with InMemoryBackendService but glad you figured it out :-)

Comment: @k.vincent by the way, if the issue is solved you can mark an answer as accepted as shown here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135826

Comment: Done, Thanks for the notice.